# What is the function of dreaming? Does a particular hormone secretion interfere with dreaming? Why do some people dream more?

Tags: neuroscience, endocrinology, sleep, dreaming

I'm really interested to know when we are sleeping how a series of stories come to our mind that we called this process dreaming. If you know a useful article on this topic, please tell me thanks.

Comment: Welcome. I see 3 different questions in the title, and a 4th in the main body. We encourage clear, focused questions, preferably 1 question per post. We also ask you to provide us with some background to narrow down the scope of the question and give us a lead in which direction you are seeking answers. So could you tell us your findings or thoughts so far investigating this topic? Have a look at the section on [asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the help center. Cheers.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1345/). Researching & understanding sleep is *hard*, even without going into dreams. I'm not an expert, but my best guess is that a lot of this is just not currently known.

Comment: Hi @Zahra - normally we strongly encourage edits to improve questions, and I like many that you've made, however they change your question a little too much for one that already has an answer. I'd strongly encourage you to both A) Edit this question along the lines of AliceD's suggestions, without disrupting the central point of the original question, and B) Ask a new question along the lines of your edits - I think that second question will be a good one. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your guidance AliceD .I will regard these points in my future questions and in this case l tried to explain more in the body and I have changed my question too.

Comment: Thanks Bryan for your points. I changed my question . whats your idea about this new one?

Comment: @Zahra Hi, sorry for the confusion - I've rolled your question back to a previous state, because the edits you made invalidate an existing answer - it changes the meaning of the question too much. I think your new question can be a good question but you should **ask it as a new question please**.

Answer (score 3):

**Dreams are hallucinations that occur during certain stages of sleep.** They’re strongest during REM sleep, or the rapid eye movement stage, when you may be less likely to recall your dream.
Research is yet to reveal the true reason of dreams. But we know for sure it is not one reason.

Speculated Reasons:

**1. Dreams as fight-or-flight training**

One of the areas of the brain that’s most active during dreaming is the **amygdala**. The amygdala is the part of the brain associated with the survival instinct and the fight-or-flight response.

One theory suggests that because the amygdala is more active during sleep than in your waking life, it may be the brain’s way of getting you ready to deal with a threat.

**2. Dreams as memory aides**

One widely held theory about the purpose of dreams is that they help you store important memories and things you’ve learned, get rid of unimportant memories, and sort through complicated thoughts and feelings.

Research shows that **sleep helps store memories.** If you learn new information and sleep on it, you’ll be able to recall it better than if asked to remember that information without the benefit of sleep.

How dreams affect memory storage and recall isn’t clearly understood yet.

**3. Creative times!**

One theory for why we dream is that it helps facilitate our creative tendencies. Artists of all kinds credit dreams with inspiring some of their most creative work. You may have awakened at times in your life with a great idea for a movie or a song, too.
Without the logical part of the brain working, emotional and illogical thoughts take over your mind!

Eectroencephalography (EEG), electro-oculography (EOG), and 
electromyography (EMG) are used to monitor neurological data from the brain to reveal information about neurological activities in the sleeping brain.

Here is a scientific literature (pdf) you can go through for in-depth study ( this link leads to ResearchGate page, you can read it there or download the pdf) :
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281071308_The_Role_of_Dreams_in_the_Evolution_of_the_Human_Mind

Comment: Thanks alot Navoneel.